# bootstrap framework with google material or apple design guideline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design

i am relatively knew to front end development and was told to develop a simple page with bootstrap framework, using Microsoft, google material or apple design guidelines, i know bootstrap but i am completely knew to these design guidelines, based on the research i have done i feel like google material design would be my best option (i could be wrong), but i cant figure out the implementation details about it and how should i go about using bootstrap framework in conjunction with material design guidelines, i dont know where to start, any tips on where to start and how to go about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good start since it is official documentation from Google on material design: https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html

There's even a modified/tweaked version of Bootstrap that has material design components: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

It's pretty easy to follow and material design is beautiful. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS for material design (Check Materialize or MDL)

But if you want to use Bootstrap for that, you need to get the unminified CSS and start adjusting CSS parameters to match the guidelines.

It's long and you'll be reinventing the wheels, but if it's for education purpose, go ahead!

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

There are a fair amount of existing templates built on bootstrap that claim to follow Material Design guidelines pretty closely.  Google them together, or start here https://superdevresources.com/material-design-bootstrap-themes/  It's likely one of these could satisfy your management out of the box :-)